# Free disk space when installing debian?

Tags: linux

I am currently installing Debian on VirtualBox. I want to partition the disk so that there is free space left over.

How can this be done? Should I choose manual partitioning? If so how should I allocate disk space? I hope to use this system as a base distro for building LFS after some time and intend to use the free space to create that partition.

All advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do manual partitioning and leave some unpartitioned space that you will be able to use in the future. But since you are using a virtual machine, you can attach more disks quite easily in the future when you need them.